# Java BinaryHeap not working on A* (not sorted)

Tags: java, heap

I am using this implementation of Heap for A* algorithm:

https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse373/11wi/homework/5/BinaryHeap.java

I slightly modified it but only adding `contains` method and renaming `remove` to `poll`, because I previously used `PriorityQueue` but it didn't work.

Here is my implementation of `Comparable<Spot>` interface:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Spot o) {
    Double.compare(getF(), o.getF());
}
```

`getF()` returns double...

however when I print the Heap with all the `getF()`s I see this:

```
1. 176.0
2. 175.0
3. 180.0
4. 176.0
5. 223.0
6. 182.0
7. 146.0
8. 177.0
9. 87.0
10. 202.0
...
```

Now the 175 is wrong because it's lower than 176, 87 is also wrong...

The same exact thing happened to me with `PriorityQueue`, what am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**
Here is my A* implementation:

```
public List<Spot> process(GameBodyObject me, Point target, ArrayList<GameBodyObject> others) throws Exception {

    if(grid == null) {
        throw new Exception("You have to initialize AStar first.");
    }

    grid.unsetObstacleForObject(me);

    Spot start = grid.getSpotAtPosition(me.getPosition().getX(), me.getPosition().getY());
    Spot end = grid.getSpotAtPosition(target.getX(), target.getY());

    end = grid.moveSpotSoThatItDoesntCollide(end, me.getRadius());

    Heap<Spot> openSet = new Heap<Spot>(grid.getMaxSize());
    List<Spot> closedSet = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Spot> path = new ArrayList<>();

    openSet.add(start);

    while(openSet.size() > 0) {

        /*int winner = 0;
        for(int i = 1; i < openSet.size(); i++) {
            if(openSet.get(i).getF() < openSet.get(winner).getF()) {
                winner = i;
            }
        }*/

        Spot current = openSet.poll(); //openSet.get(winner);

        int i = 1;
        for(Spot s : Arrays.asList(openSet.getArray())) {
            if(s != null) {
                System.out.println(i + ". " + s.getF());
                i++;
            }
        }

        if(current.equals(end)) {
            // We are done, reconstruct the path...
            Spot temp = current;
            path.add(temp);
            while(temp.getPrevious() != null) {
                path.add(temp.getPrevious());
                temp = temp.getPrevious();
            }

            grid.resetObstacles();
            return path;
        }

        closedSet.add(current);

        List<Spot> neighbors = current.getNeighbors();

        for(Spot neighbor : neighbors) {
            if(!closedSet.contains(neighbor) && !grid.isCollidingWithObstacle(neighbor, me.getRadius())) {
                double tempG = current.getG() + 1;
                if(openSet.contains(neighbor)) {
                    if(tempG < neighbor.getG()) {
                        neighbor.setG(tempG);
                    }
                } else {
                    neighbor.setG(tempG);
                    openSet.add(neighbor);
                }

                neighbor.setH(heuristic(neighbor, end));
                neighbor.setF(neighbor.getG() + neighbor.getH());
                neighbor.setPrevious(current);
            }
        }

    }

    grid.resetObstacles();
    return new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Comment: This is problem not your main problem but you should fix your `compareTo` don't know what it supposed to do but it doesn't respect the contract.

Comment: you could use `return Double.compare(getF(), o.getF());` in your `compareTo` method, I think this should do the same thing as you try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common problem when using Java's PriorityQueue or similar heap implementations to implement Dijkstra or A* algorithms is the missing of a `decreaseKey` method. Both Dijkstra or A* sometimes need to change the priority of an element inserted into the Heap. The only way to circumvent the missing of this functionality is to remove the element (which is slow in Java's PriorityQueue implementation) and then re-insert it.

But there is one problem with this: When removing the object from the PQ/Heap, it must still contain the "old" priority (`getF()` must still return the old value in your case), as otherwise the element may not be found. If the element already contains the new value, the PQ/Heap would look for it in the new place to be removed, instead of in the place matching the old value.

So, the sequence must be: (1) remove element from PQ, (2) adapt its weight/priority, (3) re-insert it into the PQ.

In your code, you have the following part:

```
            if(openSet.contains(neighbor)) {
                if(tempG < neighbor.getG()) {
                    neighbor.setG(tempG); // *1
                }
            } else {
                neighbor.setG(tempG);
                openSet.add(neighbor);
            }

            neighbor.setH(heuristic(neighbor, end));
            neighbor.setF(neighbor.getG() + neighbor.getH()); // *2
            neighbor.setPrevious(current);
```

If you look closely at it, you modify the weight of `neighbor` at line marked `*2` due to the change at line `*1`. To fix it, you could try the following:

```
            if(openSet.contains(neighbor)) {
                if(tempG < neighbor.getG()) {
                    openset.remove(neighbor); // *3
                    neighbor.setG(tempG);
                }
            } else {
                neighbor.setG(tempG);
                // openSet.add(neighbor); // *4
            }

            neighbor.setH(heuristic(neighbor, end));
            neighbor.setF(neighbor.getG() + neighbor.getH());
            openSet.add(neighbor); // *5
            neighbor.setPrevious(current);
```

This removes the element from the Heap if it's already there (`*3`) and inserts it only after the weight is correctly calculated (`*4`, `*5`).

**The problem now:** Your Heap-implementation does not offer such a `remove(Object)` method. Java's [PriorityQueue does](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#remove-java.lang.Object-). So you would have to change to Java's PriorityQueue, or to another Heap-Implementation that offers a `remove(Object)` method. (Or even better: a `decreaseKey` method, so one would not have to remove an re-insert the element at all).

In many Dijkstra/A*-Implementations I saw using Java's PQ, this was done wrong in the first attempt, leading to the incorrect order of the Heap.

**tl;dr:** Do not modify the weight/priority of an element already inserted into a PriorityQueue or Heap.

Comment: So then the Heap approach in Java is not any faster I think. I just saw that the guy on youtube made `24 ms` execution to `4 - 5 ms` in C#. Should I use Heap? or find the minimum in the classic `List<Spot>`?

Comment: The Heap should be faster than a List, but not necessarily faster than the PriorityQueue.

Comment: But the Heap approach is not working :) even though I used `return Double.compare(getF(), o.getF());` as you've mentioned above.

Comment: and how do you handle the cases in your code with the Heap, when the weight/priority of a node changes in your A*-implementation?

Comment: I am gonna edit my question and add the A* implementation

Comment: sorry I edited it with wrong code, now it should be fine

Comment: I don't see the problem in using a **PQ** for Dijkstra or a any A* variant. The **usual approach** is to not delete the bigger entry (it is slow, as you said) but to insert the element with smaller key. You now have two variants of the element in the PQ but that does not matter as the smallest will always come first (it is a PQ). Later you simply reject bigger elements as you already have settled the element previously. It would be nice if you could include this in your answer because your *"The only way to circumvent"* is not correct and misses this very common technique.

Comment: Yes, in theory. This would be true if you would insert something like `Tuple<Double, Spot>` into the PQ, where the key/priority remains constant for the rest of the time the element is in the PQ. But in your case, I guess the key/priority changes as it is part of the element. So even if you insert it a second (or third) time, all inserted elements will now show the same priority and thus mix up the order of your heap/pq. So even the element inserted first will now show the newer/lower key/priority.

Comment: and in your code, you don't reinsert it a second time, but just call `setG()` in case it is already contained in the heap.

Comment: Yeah, well, you never should change ordering relevant parts of elements that are inside an ordered structure. All of them will then show *strange* behavior, `PriorityQueue`, `TreeSet` and so on. Thus one usually uses some kind of **Container** class having a property like **tentative distance** and **element** and then only inserting those objevts into the queue.

Comment: But I am not using PQ anymore, I am using this `BinaryHeap` which I call `Heap`

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's PQ or (Binary)Heap, the both work the same way internally by taking the weight of an element from its internal state via the Comparator, and thus an element should not be inserted twice as the "original" weight will be lost if the element changes its weight internally.

Comment: once more cello can you please include in your answer what should I change in my implementation? I will mark it as correct answer then...

Comment: @durisvk10: it's not that easy to fix your code, and I've written most already what you must change. You change the weight of an element that is inside the Heap, this will always cause trouble. You will first have to remove it from the Heap, but your heap does not provide such a method, so you're out of luck. If you would use Java's PQ, you could use [PQ.remove](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#remove-java.lang.Object-) to remove the `neighbor` in your `if(openSet.contains(neighbor)) { if(tempG < neighbor.getG()) { ` block of code.

Comment: I'll try to integrate it into my answer

Comment: I don't want to do that... I'll stick to my `List<Spot>` version as it seems faster...